# String cutting with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like  `"home/back/step"` new string must be like `"home/back"`.

In other words, I have to remove the last word with `'/'`. Initial string always has a different length, but the format is the same `"word1/word2/word3/word4/word5...."`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any research? Please at least post a simplified example to demonstrate the issue you are having with the code

Comment: `string.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')` should do.

Comment: @31piy There are 5 answers, none of which being your solution, which is yet the most elegant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var x = "home/back/step";
var splitted = x.split("/");
splitted.pop();
var str = splitted.join("/");

console.log(str);
```

Take the string and split using `("/")`, then remove the last element of array and re-join with `("/")`

Answer (score 3):

Use `substr` and remove everything after the last `/`

```js
let str = "home/back/step";
let result = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use arrays to remove the last word

```js
const text = 'home/back/step';

const removeLastWord = s =>{
 let a = s.split('/');
 a.pop();
 return a.join('/');
}

console.log(removeLastWord(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a string in javascript into an array of values using the split() function. (pass it the value you want to split on)

```
var inputString = 'home/back/step'
var arrayOfValues = inputString.split('/');
```

Once you have an array, you can remove the final value using pop()

```
arrayOfValues.pop()
```

You can convert an array back to a string with the join function (pass it the character to place in between your values)

```
return arrayOfValues.join('/')
```

The final function would look like:

```js
function cutString(inputString) {
  var arrayOfValues = inputString.split('/')
  arrayOfValues.pop()
  return arrayOfValues.join('/')
}

console.log(cutString('home/back/step'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I got a solution

```js
var s = "your/string/fft";
var withoutLastChunk = s.slice(0, s.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(withoutLastChunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on the '/', remove the last element with pop() and then join again the elements with '/'.
Something like:

```
str.split('/');
str.pop();
str.join('/');
```

Where str is the variable with your text.